# How to pass date_from and date_to from one php to another one to do a db query

Tags: php

I use a jquery ui calendar let user choose the start and end date, click a link in first php page to do a mydql query in second php page to export the query result as a download csv file (some guys said it's impossible to do this in one page, it have to be two php pages).

My question is how to pass $date_from and $date_to from first php and how to get those value in second page.

thx

this works!
query string like this: check.php?date_from=2012-09-01&date_to=2012-09-30

and in check.php, the value can get like this:

```
$export_type = $_GET['export_type'];
$date_from = $_GET['date_from'];
$date_to = $_GET['date_to'];
```

Comment: This works.$export_type = $_GET['export_type'];
$date_from = $_GET['date_from'];
$date_to = $_GET['date_to'];

Answer (score 0):

In your html form you can set an element with a 'name' attribute and value of the `$date_from` variable and pass it to another page like:

```
<form action="next_page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="text_name" value=<?= $date_from ?> />
</form>
```

In next_page.php you can access it with the **$_POST** variable:

```
<? echo $_POST['text_name'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Ajax on one page. You can do this on one page with only one page refresh, too. There are several ways to do this. One way I can think of off the top of my head would be to accept the data from the javascript calendar via a "submit" button in a form (that is also populated with the data from your javascript calendar). Something like this:

page.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['formsubmit'])) {
    grab_form_data();
  }
?>
<html>...<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  jquery_calendar();
  populates_form_field1_below_on_select();
</script>
...
<form method="POST" action="page.php">
<input id="field1" name="field1"></input>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>
<?php
  create_csv_download_link_from_PHP_data_at_top_of_page();
?>
...
</html>
```